# Mocking getClass()

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

In Java I want to write test for method (simplified snippet):

```
public class MyClass {
    private static final Set<Class> SOME_SET = new HashSet<Class>(Arrays.asList(Foo.class, Bar.class));

    public boolean isValid(Class clazz){
        return SOME_SET.contains(clazz);
    }
}
```

The problem with following test

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

public class MyClassTest {
    @Test
    public void isValid_Foo_returnsTrue(){
        Foo foo = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
        MyClass target = new MyClass();
        assertTrue(target.isValid(foo));
   }
}
```

is that on mocked class Foo, `foo.getClass()` returns the class name with additional suffix. Something like this:

```
Foo$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$45508b12
```

Because of this reason test fails because *SOME_SET.contains(clazz)* returns *false*.

I was unable to mock *getClass()* method on Foo:

```
Mockito.when(foo.getClass()).thenReturn(Foo.class);
```

Because compiler was complaining: 
*The method thenReturn(Class<capture#1-of ? extends Foo>) in the type OngoingStubbing<Class<capture#1-of ? extends Foo>> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<Foo>)*

The question is, **how to achieve that getClass() method of mocked object returns same value as getClass() method on real(non mocked) object**?

Comment: Hmm...something wrong in your question. isValid expects a class as its param. But you pass an object in the test.

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake when i simplified the example. It should be public boolean isValid(Object object){
        return SOME_SET.contains(object.getClass());
    }

Answer (score 4):

Mockito.mock(Foo.class) results a object in type of Foo, but not exactly Foo class. As at the background it will create an anonymous proxy, which is a subclass of Foo. So, the class isn't the same.

One note to your implementation of isValid is that: do you really want to check the class, or just to check the type (that will also accept subclass, isAssignableFrom) of the class. If you check for type matching, then you can test your method with mocked class.

Also, do you think that you can somehow work on objects rather than classes (e.g. isValid(object))? Using object is a better approach in OOP than clazz in my perspective.
I would suggest:

```
    public boolean isValid(Object obj) {
        return SOME_SET.stream().anyMatch(clazz -> clazz.isInstance(obj));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I see no sense on mocking Foo on your scenario. Just pass Foo.class as param. You are checking MyClass.isValid logic, and you are not gonna check any interaction on Foo.

Comment: +1 No doubt the most intelligent answer. It's amazing how often you see people thinking they need to use mocking, when a test with no mocking is so much better...

Answer (score 1):

Simple: you can't.

Keep in mind: a **mocked** object is not really of the mocked class. It is *something* that the mocking framework creates for you to *look* like the real class. But you can't have it both ways: either something is *faked* or it is *real*.

And in your case, a reasonable test looks different anyway:

```
@Test
public void testIsValidForInvalidClass() {
  assertThat(target.isValid(String.class), is(false));
}

@Test
public void testIsValidForValidClass() {
  assertThat(target.isValid(Foo.class), is(true));
}
```

for example. There is no point in mocking **Class** objects in the first place. As you can *easily* construct and pass **real** objects of class Class!

Comment: I understand. Anyway, you rock :)

Comment: LOL You really make me laugh :)

Comment: This answer is correct that no mocking is needed here, but flat out wrong about a mocked object not being an instance of the mocked class. The fact that libraries like Mockito use proxy objects for mocks (which are instances of dynamically generated subclasses) is merely a detail of the mocking implementation approach employed by said libraries. Other libraries, such as PowerMock and JMockit (my own) use a different approach where such proxies are not created.

Comment: @Rogério How do you then create an object that returns Foo.class upon calling getClass()? And what does a mock created by JMockit return when getClass() is called?

Comment: JMockit *redefines* the mocked class ("redefinition" is an ability of the JVM similar to the class *definition* performed by class loaders - it's made available to Java code through the `java.lang.instrument` API added in Java 5, but exists internally since long before, as it's used by the "HotSwap" debugging mechanism). Since a mocked class itself is redefined, all of its actual instances become "mocked" (until the class is redefined back to its original definition), so calls to `getClass()` return the actual class, which is now redefined.

Answer (score 0):

When initializing the object 'foo', just create an object of type Foo instead of creating a mock of Foo. For example, if possible:

```
Foo foo = new Foo()
```

Comment: That would be nice if it was possible, but in real life Foo is GWT widget that can't be instantiated in test, so the only way to use it in a test is to create a mock.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with a, currently incubating, alternative mock maker implementation. See [here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2#mock-the-unmockable-opt-in-mocking-of-final-classesmethods) how to enable it.
Calling `getClass` on such mocks returns the original class so `equals` will work as expected.